# Building a Bluetooth device for Apple

Tags: java, iphone, build, bluetooth-lowenergy

So I'm looking to make my own not so smart "smart" watch Bluetooth device. From what I've found online, I will need some sort of "brain", a thing capable of using BLE, and since I want a display, also an led screen. I need to display the time, and be notified when a call or text is received.

My question comes down to these 3 points-

1. What should I use/buy for the brain? I'm assuming some sort or variant of a little cpu? I'm also going to need the Bluetooth side of it, but I'm unsure of what I would need that is capable of giving BLE to my device.
2. Is it possible to make the software side out of this in Java? It is the only language I know extensively, but I'm willing to learn any of it is needed.
3. Is there anything special I would have to do to pair it with an IPhone (such as make an app, code it a certain way, etc)

I'm sorry if at any point I'm too vague (I don't know enough not to be) or if I'm oblivious to any well known facts; this is my first time ever building an electronic device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If you would like a smaller cheaper solution and you're somewhat accustomed to working with micro-controllers, I would say look at something like [Arduino Micro](http://store-usa.arduino.cc/products/a000053) plus a BLE shield or another brand micro-controller.
2. Arduino uses its own functional language that's fairly easy to learn coming from `java` and any other micro-controller would probably use `C`, if you decide to go that route. A micro-controller would most likely not support `java`, because the `JVM` is simply too large and has too much overhead for a tiny cpu.
3. The time should not be an issue to update via BLE. You can implement the calling and SMS via the ANCS protocol.

[Here](http://www.instructables.com/id/Make-your-own-smart-watch/) is a good example/tutorial for an arduino "smartwatch".

Comment: I edited my question to be more specific on the type of device I want it to be, thanks for the help

Comment: When you say "does not allow sms to be seen" does that mean the text inside the sms or the entirety of the sms? And would I need an app for the "smart" watch to get any info from the iPhone?

Comment: Unless the iPhone is jailbroken it is impossible to access the SMS stack (sms received event or read the sms content). I do believe it is possible with Android, but I'm not entirely sure.

Comment: Whether you need an app or not depends on what kind of info. You can stream music or get the time (I believe, but don't quote me) without an app. As for the jailbroken part I know nothing about. From google searching I found that the SMS stack is stored as an SQLite database located at `/var/mobile/Library/SMS/sms.db`. You would need an app to access this, however, I'm not sure how to develop apps for jailbroken iPhones.

Comment: I really appreciate the help. I'll get there eventually, now on to learn how to build a jailbreak app :)

Comment: Actually, Apple provides the ANCS protocol which exposes call details, SMS and other notifications via Bluetooth. It does not require a jailbreak

Comment: Really? So I would just need make/find an app that could communicate with the "smart" watch?

Comment: You need an app that helps your watch find the phone and you need to implement the ANCS protocol in your watch

Comment: @Paulw11 sorry for the long wait. Thanks for pointing that out to me. I updated my answer.